# Changed Deployment iOS to 4.0 from 5.0 - Now wont run on my iPhone, but does on simulators

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, build, xcode4.2

Ive an app that is finished and works when set to deploy on iOS 5.0.  Ive since had to change the deployment setting to make it support down to iOS 4.0.  Everything code-wise is ok - I just had to change some UIActivityIndicatorView stuff that only works on 5.0.  It will compile and run fine on the simulator - both 4.3, and 5.0.  But it will no longer run on my local device, an iPhone 4 with iOS 5.0.  I get the message on building :

error: There is no SDK with specified name or path /(Path to my project)/Multiple

Ive tried changing build architectures so that armv6 as well as armv7 is supported.  Im not sure what else Ive done wrong.  Base SDK is set to 5.0; Deployment is set to 4.0.  Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The base SDK should always be set to "Latest iOS". You probably only have device SDK 5.1 which is causing a problem.

Comment: Base SDK is set to Latest iOS (5.0).  Any other ideas?

Comment: The latest SDK should be 5.1. What version of Xcode are you running?

Comment: Its XCode 4.2.  You think updating to latest will help matters?  Bearing in mind it all worked fine just til I changed that deployment iOS setting?

Comment: Have updated to 4.3, seems to have caught a few things, and also reverted to previous working build.  Seems the build settings can get mixed up between SDKs and deployments etc.  Take plenty of snapshots when changing this stuff, seems to be the way to go.